# When I try delete a record, it creates a new one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to do a simple deletion of a record in the database.

```
<b> <%= button_to "Cancel your invitation", { :controller=>"invites", :method => 'destroy', :id => invite.id },
:confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this invite?" %></b>
```

I specify the the controller because I am doing this action from a User view.

When I click the button, it creates a blank entry for a new record. So why would it use a create method when I specified a destroy one?

Some more into:
My config/routes is as simple as can be:

> resources :invites

My controller is quite basic too:

```
  def create
    @invite = Invite.new(params[:invite])
    if @invite.save
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end



  def destroy
    Invite.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to current_user
  end
```

Comment: What does your controller look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misused the methods. It should be:

```
<b>
  <%= button_to "Cancel your invitation", invite, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this invite?", :method => :delete %>
</b>
```

There are 2 points.

1) For `resources :invites`, the destroy method needs `delete`. Without passing `:method => :delete` to `button_to` would by default use `:method => :post`, which is the create method. That's why you created a new record instead of destroying it.

2) As you are using resources, you have better choice for the route instead of `{:controller => "invites", :action => "destroy", :id => invite.id}` (note that it was `:action`)

You could use `invite_path(invite)` or just `invite` just like my example above. With the `:method => :delete` this gives you the destroy method. (so with :post for create, :put for update)

Comment: Thanks, I think this works (can't be too certain though since I get an error when trying to delete) so I will mark this correct for now.

Comment: Should my controller destroy action be the same?

Comment: No change to the controller and route part (use the `resources :invites` and standard destroy action is ok)

Answer (score 2):

I think, you need to use delete method instead of destroy.

Comment: +1 and, you should have an action named destroy in your invites controller.

Comment: @SpyrosP: yes, it should be there :)

Comment: Same problem with :method => 'delete'

Comment: you also need to mention the action in url, :action=>'destroy'